# Login Visual Basic con base de datos

Tags: vb.net

Buenas, veran estoy creando un login en visual studio utilizando SQL Server Compact pero no se como obtener los datos resultantes de la sentencia y compararlos, tengo esto:

```
 Dim sqlcon As New SqlCeConnection("Data Source=C:\Usuarios.sdf; Persist Security Info=False;")
 Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCeCommand()

    Try

        Dim sqltext As String
        sqltext = "Select * from Usuarios where Nombre = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and Contra = '" + TextBox2.Text + "'"

        sqlcmd.CommandText = sqltext
        sqlcmd.Connection = sqlcon
        sqlcon.Open()
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


        sqlcon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Es la primera vez que lo utilizo y estoy un poco verde, ojala puedan ayudarme. Basicamente lo que quiero hacer es en caso de que se haya encontrado un registro, es decir, sea True, acceder a otro Form. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar tienes que hacer un count en tu consulta para que te devuelva en valor 1 si es correcto o 0 si es erroneo, por ejemplo:

```
public bool ValidacionUsuario(string varnombre, string varpassword)
{
     sqlcmd.CommandText = "Select Count(*) from Usuarios where Nombre = '" & varnombre & "' and Contra = '" + varpassword + "'";
     sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     sqlcmd.Connection = sqlcon;
     int count = Convert.ToInt32(sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar());
     if(count == 0)
      {
     return false;
      }
      else
      {
      return true;
      }
}
```

Te recomiendo encriptar tu contraseña.

Comment: Funciona!!!, mil gracias ;) .

Comment: Si te funcionó puedes darle aceptar respuesta al lado izquierdo :).